# How to print following map objects? Python3

Tags: python

Here's the code:

```py
a = ((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 2))
a = map(lambda x : map(lambda x: x**2, x), a)
print(tuple(a))  # doesn't work
```

How can I unmap this object?

Comment: What are you trying to do with that nested `map`?  That is, what output are you expecting?

Comment: a = ((1, 4), (9, 16), (25, 4))

Comment: `lambda x: tuple(map(...))`…

Comment: Or `tuple(tuple(j ** 2 for j in i) for i in a)`…

Comment: What "doesn't work", precisely?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, It's supposed that a tuple will be printed not just a map object